# Como restaurar do Git um arquivo modificado que deu erro?

Tags: git

Turma, fiz um commit (e depois o push) de um arquivo no git até onde estava tudo bem. Quando voltei para continuar o trabalho, fiz algumas alterações que resultaram em erros e bugs. Dessa vez não fiz commit ainda e quero restaurar tudo que fiz até o último commit pois me perdi nas alterações e quero recomeçar do último commit correto.

Comment: git reset --hard, talvez?

Comment: Vc quer descartar as alterações atuais e deixar igual no último commit que vc deu push?

Comment: exato! quero recomeçar de onde parei no último commit. o que eu fiz depois deu erro e não consigo encontrar o erro.

Comment: Certo! Caso alguma resposta tenha resolvido seu problema considere marcar como aceita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para descartar **TUDO** o que vc fez localmente:

```
git reset --hard
```

---

Para descartar todas as alterações de um arquivo específico:

```
git checkout -- <arquivo>
```

---

Para colocar na pilha tudo o que vc fez e ter possibilidade de recuperar posteriormente:

```
git stash
```

Answer (score 0):

**step 1**: "esconder" as modificações que você ainda não comitou.

```
git stash save <descrição>
```

**step 2**: resetar o ultimo commit da branch levando as modificações dele para staging area.

```
git reset HEAD~
```

*aqui (step 2) caso queira, você pode commitar novamente as modificações ou remove-las de vez com: git checkout -- < arquivo>*

**step 3** (opcional): recuperar as modificações "escondidas" no step 1 e aplicar novamente sob o código.

```
git stash list
```

*lista todas as stashs feitas*

```
git stash apply stash@{numero-da-stash}
```

*aplica a stash selecionada sob o código*

*ao aplicar a stash, podem acontecer conflitos que devem ser resolvidos*

**WARNING**

Depois que você fizer as alterações que deseja e fizer um próximo commit, ao tentar realizar o push novamente, você receberá um erro porque a arvore local estará diferente da remota dado que você fez um push e depois resetou o commit localmente. Para proseguir com o push você pode usar:

```
git push --force
```

*antes de dar esse comando certifique-se de que sua branch está organizada com os commits que você deseja, porque essa branch substituirá a remota*